# Gson.toJson() persist parent and children fields where children fields are dominant

Tags: json, parsing, kotlin, gson

For example i have 3 classes

```
class Grandad {
var lastname : String = "Smith"
var firstName : String = "John"
}
```

```
class Dad : Grandad() {
override firstname: String = "Jack"
var hasPersonalComputer = true
}
```

```
class Teenager : Dad() {
override var firstname : String = "Chris"
override var hasPersonalComputer = false
var hasSmartPhone = true
}
```

Now when i do something like this:

```
println(Gson().toJson(Teenager()))
```

I would like it to output this, take note that all the field will be printed but in the overriden cases the child is dominant otherwise assume the parent's value to be default

```
{
firstname: Chris
lastname: Smith
hasPersonalComputer: true
hasSmartPhone: true
}
```

However the above crashes with the following message:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: class Teenager declares multiple JSON fields named firstname
```

Ideally I would like to achieve this without writing boilerplate for all my classes. It would be nice if this could be done with some reflection of some kind. I'm not really concerned about performance as this will run once a day and the output will be cached in a database.

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon `Klaxon` Library and this does exactly what I need it to.

Answer (score 0):

Can you maybe elaborate how you did this? When I use Klaxon, it only ever gives me the members declared in the immediate class, but never the superclass fields. I traced it to this line:

`obj::class.declaredMemberProperties` in the type `JsonValue`, which does not include the superclass member properties. `obj::class.memberProperties` would.